# Jinja template - remove duplicate from table column

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I created a table with 3 columns.

- Column one is the main test name.
- Column two is the sub-test name.
- Column three is the pass/fail status.

I would like to remove duplicates in column so that sub-test and status can look like they are grouped with the main test.

I tried to use the unique filter in the html below `<td>{{ value['status'][0][0]|unique }}</td>` but no luck there.

Basically trying to remove duplicates from column 1 of my table.

```html
<table style="width: 100%" class="flex-container">
    <tbody>
        {% for key, value in testCaseStatusDict.items() %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ value['status'][0][0] }}</td>

                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><b>{{ value['testCaseName']}}</b></td>

                {% for status in value['status']%}
                    {% if status[2] == 'FAIL' %}
                        <td style="background-color: red; text-align: center"><br>{{ status[2] }} <br> {{ status[3] }}</td>
                    {% else %}
                        <td style="background-color: green; text-align: center"><br>{{ status[2] }} <br> {{ status[3] }}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Desired look:

[image: Desired look]

Actual output:

[image: Actual output]

Comment: the image of how they currently grouped not display? what's your view.py ?

Comment: I dont have access to that file at the moment, but I added sample images of what I'm trying to build to. Also, I searched but could not find a way to check a specific value of a cell in a table on jinja. I was trying to write an if-else to check if a value in column 1 already exist, if so, then dont add text to the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: Check if you are already in your actual test case if yes don't print the status again else print it.

```
{% set status_before = [] %}    
{% for key, value in testCaseStatusDict.items() %}
    <tr>    
        {% if value['status'][0][0] in status_before %}
            <td></td>
        {% else %}
            <td>{{ value['status'][0][0] }}</td>
            {% set __ = status_before.append(value['status'][0][0]) %}
        {% endif %}
    ...
```

@Edit Try it with mutable list, even if it's ugly. Looks like updating a variable inside a loop is not supported: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/641

Comment: I tried adding this, but it doesnt seem to make a difference. The set status_before in the else statement is not updating.

Comment: @VanHour I updated my post, try it with mutable list.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for your help and quick replies!

Comment: @VanHour you're welcome. if it helped you please accept it as answer so people with similar problems see that it's already solved.